# An analogue of the equidistribution theorem?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, ergodic-theory

Suppose that $(n_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a given increasing sequence of positive integers.

Does there exist an (irrational) number $a$ such that 
$\{an_k\}:=(a n_k)\text{mod }1 \rightarrow 1/2$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: No, of course not in this generality: if $n_k=k$, then $ak$ will be dense in the unit circle (I assume you meant the fractional part of $an_k$, not $an_k$ itself).

Comment: Yes, sorry just edited it.

Comment: On the other hand, if $n_k=10^{k^2}$, then $a=0.05005000050000005\dots$ should do.

Comment: There is an old theorem of Pollington (1979, Illinois J Math) showing that if $(n_k)$ is lacunary ($n_{k+1}/n_k\ge s$ for all $k$) for some $s>1$, then there exists a $\beta>0$ (depending on $s$) and an $a$ such that ${an_k}$ lies in $[\beta,1-\beta]$ for all $k$. A corollary of the proof is if $n_{k+1}/n_k\to\infty$, then there exists $a$ such that ${an_k}\to \frac 12$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no in general. For many increasing sequences $(n_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ of positive integers, it happens for every irrational number $a$ that $\{an_k\}$ is dense or even equidistributed in the unit circle. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $n_{2k}=k^2, n_{2k+1}=k^2+1$ is a counterexample.

Indeed, if $\{ n_k a \} \to \frac{1}{2}$ then $\{ n_{2k}a \} \to \frac{1}{2}$ and $\{ n_{2k+1} a\} \to \frac{1}{2}$.

This implies that $a= n_{2k+1}a-n_{2k} a= \lfloor n_{2k+1}a\rfloor+ \{ n_{2k+1}a \} - \lfloor n_{2k}a\rfloor- \{ n_{2k}a \} $ and hence
$$ a \pmod{1} \equiv  \{ n_{2k+1}a \} - \{ n_{2k}a \} \to 0 \pmod{1} $$

This shows that $a \in \mathbb Z$, which contradicts  $\{ n_k a \} \to \frac{1}{2}$.

The same is true about any subsequence containing infinitely many pairs of consecutive intgers.

**P.S.** On another hand, if $a$ is an irrational number, it follows from the denseness of $\{ na \}$ that there exists some $n_k$ such that $\{ n_ka \} \to \frac{1}{2}$.

This shows that there are many subsequences with this property, and I think one can argue that there are uncounatbly many such sequences.

Comment: Why is $a(\text{mod} 1)\equiv \{n_{2k+1}a\}-\{n_{2k}a\}$? It could happen that $\{n_{2k+1}a\}-\{n_{2k}a\}<0$.

Comment: @JohnSmith It is congruence $\pmod{1}$ not equality of fractional parts. $$a \equiv b \pmod{1}$$ means $a-b \in \mathbb Z$. Your point is exactly why I switched to $\pmod{1}$ there.